# Spring WebFlux Validate OpenAPI Spec Against request

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-webflux, openapi

I am trying to validate if OpenAPI specification matches the implementation in Spring Boot Reactive Microservice (*WebClient*). I bumped into this library [swagger-request-validator](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/swagger-request-validator/src/master/), however, it does not have any implementation for the WebClient (*the one provided as under web client uses Rest Template*). Is there any open-source library that can check API spec against implementation? I am trying to make a call to the service that will run against the actual implementation, and at the same time will validate if the request/response matches the OpenAPI specification.

Answer (score 0):

UPD: sorry, I've just noticed that you want to validate on client side. I don't have such use case and my answer is about server-side, but you can have a look.

---

You can try this library: https://github.com/cdimascio/openapi-spring-webflux-validator

Here is brief example in kotlin

```kotlin
val validator = Validate.configure(
    openApiSwaggerPath = "http://your-swagger-addr",
)

data class YourRequestBody(...)
                                                   
fun handle(request: ServerRequest) =
    validator.request(request)
        .withBody<YourRequestBody> { requestBody ->
            // process request...
            // return Mono<ServerResponse>
        }
```

In my case I'm serving swagger-ui from the same service using spring boot 3.1.5. I had to manually specify dependencies to resolve some conflicts. Here is my gradle configuration.

```
dependencies {
    //...
    implementation('org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui:2.2.0')
    // validator has not been updated since 2022. It uses atlassian validator from 2021, which is incompatible
    // with new swagger-models from webflux-ui.
    implementation('io.github.cdimascio:openapi-spring-webflux-validator:4.2.0')
    // Manually setting version of atlassian validator works for now.
    implementation("com.atlassian.oai:swagger-request-validator-core:2.39.0")
    /...
}
```